# How to get balance on metamask all network [bsc , eth, cro, etc] using web3modal

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, web3-providers

how to display the balance for metamask using web3modal with various networks, for example I am on the mainet bsc network I display the bnb balance, and if I use the ether network what appears is the balance of eth